# Zipping/archiving old log files?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Some time ago I wrote a [blog post](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/roll-sitecore-logs-automatically) about rolling the Sitecore logs:

Now I'm on a project that wants to keep their logs for 3 years, but doesn't want to use disk space. I modified it from an initialize pipeline processor to an agent and to compress the logs to a different directory.

Is there a better way than current solution as below?   Or alternative solutions that would work outside the Asp.Net process?

```xml
<agent type="Whatever.Tasks.LogFileManager" method="Run" interval="00:00:30"/>
<minAge>00:00:30</minAge>
```

```cs
namespace Whatever.Tasks
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using Sitecore.IO;
    using Sitecore.Configuration;
    using Sitecore.Zip;

    public class LogFileManager
    {
        // files must be this old
        public TimeSpan MinAge { get; set; }

        public void Run()
        {
            // where the logs are
            string logDirectory = FileUtil.MapPath(Settings.LogFolder);

            // where the zip files go
            string archiveDirectory = Path.Combine(
                FileUtil.MapPath(Settings.DataFolder), 
                "logArchive");

            // where the log files will go temporarily (possibly avoided)
            string tempDirectory = Path.Combine(
                archiveDirectory,
                Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoNow);

            if (!Directory.Exists(tempDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory);
            }

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(logDirectory))
            {
                // check min age only if needed
                if (this.MinAge > TimeSpan.Zero)
                { 
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                    DateTime check = fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc > fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc
                        ? fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc
                        : fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc;

                    if (DateTime.UtcNow - check < this.MinAge)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    File.Move(file, tempDirectory + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    // locked, probably to ASP.NET?
                }
            }

            // if there are no files in the temporary directory, 
            // don't create the zip file.
            if (Directory.GetFiles(tempDirectory).Length > 0)
            {
                string zipFile = tempDirectory + ".zip";

                using (ZipWriter zipWriter = new ZipWriter(zipFile))
                {
                    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(tempDirectory))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
                        {
                            zipWriter.AddEntry(FileUtil.GetFileName(file), fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Directory.Delete(tempDirectory, true /*recursive*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The editor considers text as a code when it is indented with at least four spaces. If you paste C# code the namespace is treated as text because it is not indented at all. The same about trailing bracket.

Comment: You can ask to-the-point questions here, you can't blog here. For more visit here http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Just wondering why you would want cleanup/archiving of files to be handled in the application. The IT department handles this - they have scripts for archiving IIS logs as well and can re-use them for Sitecore log files..    Ever since I had a Sitecore5.x site crash because he couldn't clean the MediaCache folder anymore I got quite anxious about this. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Szymon! It sounds like I can simply exclude the namespace declaration (my usings go inside that declaration, indented four spaces) and closing curly brace.

Maybe I should post these kinds of things on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as I certainly would like to get feedback from non-Sitecore developers about Sitecore APIs and coding patterns, as well as learn better coding techniques. But then we would need something like http://scodereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Gatogordo: Agreed, but this is a requirement from IT. One issue is that they have very little disk space, and Sitecore can generate quite a volume of log. Another, default Sitecore configuration cleans its own logs, so at the very least, we need to disable that. Without some cleanup/compression, the application will eventually fail (or at least stop logging), & my employer (as the implementation partner) would likely be held responsible for that. Another is that they do not seem to have the tools, knowledge of the application & tools, time or other resources to implement solutions.

Comment: Are you able to use database storage for logs instead, like SQL Server or MongoDB? Appenders for both are available (although, you'll obviously be shifting the issue elsewhere...)

Comment: @jammykam: Interesting thought, but would this not preclude use of Sitecore Log Analyzer https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx? I am not sure that this is a firm requirement, but without it, we may need more development work to meet their error management/audit/reporting requirements.

Comment: if moving the logs to db records is not an option if you just need to delete old logs can't you schedule a task that clears the data folder for logs over 3 years and zips the remaining ones? configure it to run on a daily basis or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using .net code or storing logs in the database:

We used the `forfiles` command for things like this. Place the command(s together) in a batch file and have that executed as a scheduled task on the server. Works fast and puts no extra load on your .net application.
You can delete files with it (based on date), adding zip functionality (e.g. with 7zip) should be fairly easy.

E.g. to delete all .log files in a path, last modified as least 5 days ago:

```
forfiles /S /P <path> /M *.log /D -5 /C "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

In the command (cmd) you could 
More info on the parameters: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.11).aspx